# KDB :How to write select statement where table contains multi values space separated

Tags: kdb

I have to query the table to fetch values for a column which contains i.e. `Class 1,Class 2,Class 3,Class 4` using select query on KDB .
I am able to fetch for a single value but not for multiple values.
I tried in below way :

```
http://iapp123.qa.abc.com:2345/?select from classDetails where standard in
`$("Class 1")
```

Here `classDetails` is table name and `standard` is column name.

But dont know how to use it using multiple values in query condition i.e. also adding `Class 2,Class 3,Class 4` also

Comment: Can you give sample table example to understand it more clearly.

Comment: name  standard  subject
-----------------------
Alex  Class 1   Physics
Eddie Class 2   Chemistry
Stark Class 3   Maths

Comment: Ok. There are couple of options but I think Igor answer is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cast "Class 1" to a symbol I think it is safe to assume that a type of `standard` column is symbol as well. In this case

```
select from classDetails where standard in `$("Class 1"; "Class 2"; "Class 3")
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

using `like` :

```
select from classDetails  where standard  like "Class [1-3]"
```